# Simple authentication to google contacts no longer works

Tags: ruby, authentication, contacts, google-contacts-api

I use some ruby scripts to sync emails with the gem 'gmail' and also use the gem "google_drive".
Both let you authenticate using your google emailaddress and password. Nice and easy.

When it comes to using google contacts things get difficult. The examples i found that just used this authentication no longer work (eg [contacts](http://rubygems.org/gems/contacts), blackbook, google-contacts etc), they are years old and with google changing their authorization regurarly that doen't surprise.

I only find gems and examples using OAuth2 that are relativy recent but that is complicatede and until now i didn't succeed in making them work, they also require you to run a site to redirect your token to. They are also targeted to rails developers.

So here is my question: Is there any gem still working that uses the above simple authentication ?
I want to run this script on multiple computers and don't want to use a site.
Please provide a working sample.

I tried dozens of samples and include a few that no longer work.

I allready lost a day on this so if someone could help ? Please ..

using blackbook

```
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']="C:/users/gebruiker/cert.pem"
require 'blackbook'
contacts = Blackbook.get :username => 'myemail@gmail.com', :password => 'password'
```

using contacts

```
require 'contacts'
contacts = Contacts::Gmail.new(login, password).contacts
```

Comment: Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow when you ask for recommendations for an off-site library or gem.

Comment: it's the kind of information everyone is looking for Tin Man, and i don't know a better place to ask this, it shouldn't be off-topic

Comment: It is, because the majority of Stack Overflow users have decided it is. Too many self-promotions occurred, and it's too easy for us to do initial searches and weed out things that don't work for our own particular purposes. Stack Overflow is for problems with code, not the initial discovery step.

Comment: then weed out these promotions, i DO have problems with the code i published, i wish someone answers with a solution with these or other gems, i don't care

Comment: While I understand your dilemma, you need to work within the system. I am not the system, I'm trying to help you get an answer that works for you, however, you have to help. What has your searches revealed, and what have you determined are the best solutions for you? What have you found as you tried them? When you tried them, did one work better than the others? What failed in that one?